# Using tbl with in_schema creating syntax error using FreeTDS

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, dbplyr

I'm trying to create a lazy table in order to use the `dplyr` sql backend within Shiny Server on Ubuntu using `tbl` is throwing a syntax error.

```
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(pool)
library(DBI)

pool <- dbPool(odbc::odbc(),
               driver = "FreeTDS", 
               server = "server", 
               database = "database", 
               uid = "uid", 
               pwd = "password", 
               port = 1433)
data <- tbl(pool, in_schema("schema.dbo", "table"))

Error: <SQL> 'SELECT *
    FROM schema.dbo.table AS "zzz1"
    WHERE (0 = 1)'
     nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'zzz1'.
```

The code runs without error in a Windows environment and the generated SQL statement runs successfully when executed in SQL. The pool object has also made a successful connection as the executed query from shiny shows up in the logs.

I've also checked to make sure the connection information is correct within odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini.

Is there a known issue with using dplyr with FreeTDS driver to work with SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response, but hopefully will be helpful for someone.

See this [issue on the dbplyr github](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/246) for the answer.

Running `DBI::dbExecute(pool, "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON")` should resolve your issue.

Thanks to JakeRuss and hadley (in the github dbplyr issue link above) for their work in debugging this.